# Yahoo-Pipes, Best Practices: 'Loop with a String Regex' vs. 'Regex'

Tags: yahoo-pipes, heuristics

What is a useful heuristic to consider when deciding between a 'Loop with a String Regex' and a 'Regex' module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://discuss.pipes.yahoo.com/Message_Boards_for_Pipes/threadview?m=tm&bn=pip-DeveloperHelp&tid=9666&mid=9677&tof=2&rt=2&frt=2&off=1